# Controlled folder access blocks svchost.exe application

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-defender, svchost, controlled-folder-access

Yesterday I enabled [controlled folder access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/controlled-folders) in [Microsoft Defender Antivirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Defender) (*Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Settings > Controlled folder access = On*). Today every few minutes I get the message that *svchost.exe* tries to write in *%userprofile%\Videos* directory. Why does *svchost.exe* access *%userprofile%\Videos* directory, and is it safe to allow it to do this?

The message I get states that: "You can allow apps to access your protected folders, but you should only allow apps that you trust".

I have Windows 10 Pro version 2004.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Controlled folder access feature is new to Windows defender and Windows 10, and is experimental and very buggy. It protects folder Documents, Pictures, Videos by default and does not let any process access and write there. You should turn it off to get rid of this messages. Go to Windows Security > Virus and threat protection > Virus and threat protection settings > Controlled folder access and turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This feature is in Microsoft Defender since version 1709, so almost for 3 years. I don't know if it can be called experimental, if everybody is recommended to turn it off :D Do you have some Microsoft source which recommends to disable it or any more info, please?
I like the idea of protecting my private data, because several years ago the data on one of my computers were encrypted by ransomware.

Comment: No, it is not of any use. You should turn it off otherwise it will co tune to pop up nagging messages. (*If this has solved your problem you can consider accepting it*)

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. The question is what is it doing there and should I allow svchost.exe to access the files... Since svchost.exe is a Windows system process, you should allow it. Be sure to check if it's svchost.exe located in Windows\system32.

Comment: @Dude so its windows process, but 3rd party virus can use it to configure windows and operate for virus needs, so when svhost is beeing used for something fishy- when this option is on, then you are safe. Virus makers are swarming in forums posting to turn off, so there would be some infected computers. 
https://superuser.com/a/1653562/64599

Comment: There's nothing that protects another process from calling itself svchost.exe either, so you can't be sure it's actually the system svchost.exe that is trying to access the protected folders.

Answer (score 4):

Protected access prevents ransomware from encrypting your files. It blocked svchost.exe because "one of the svchost processes may be host to a 3rd party service, which Windows Security is not trustful of." See:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/svchostexe-protected-folder-access-blocked/6ec440ad-ff58-4eb4-b835-8605da61a56e

Answer (score 0):

There is zero good reason to turn off controlled folder access.
Nagging popup messages are not more intrusive than hackers completely hijacking your system.

And for the record, there is also no good reason svchost should need to access your videos folder. I get this same popup message, and my videos folder is empty.

Leave controlled folder access on and ignore the messages. It's the safest option for the health of your computer.